# C# timer while function is running

Tags: c#, timer, task

I have a function (call it Process()) that does some processing. I want to call it at a point and at the same time start a timer. Then I want to call the next statement after the function only if 100 seconds have elapsed (and of course the function has finished). I don't want to sleep for 100 seconds as sleep suggests that the processor is just waiting - I want the processing function to be running while the timer is ticking.

I'm not sure what I should use. Some say use a task. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int Ticks = Environment.TickCount;

ReallyBigFunction();

if(Environment.TickCount - Ticks > 100*1000)
{
    // The function took more than 100 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest spinning the function off on another thread, then sleep for 100 seconds on your main thread.  When your main thread wakes up again you can check whether or not the function thread has completed and join it back into the main program flow.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want the process to be running, you may want to start a new thread that will wait the time you need:

```
ThreadStart start = delegate()
{
    Thread.Sleep(100000);
    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        new Action(ThreadDoSomething)); //The function who will execute what you want to do.

};

new Thread(start).Start();
```

Note : The current code will give you access to the interface.